# Create MySQL infinite loop

Tags: c++, mysql, mysql-connector

I am working on creating test functions for a project that work independently of what data is currently in the database. Specifically, I want to have a test case that demonstrates OPT_READ_TIMEOUT is working. I found out that MySQL has while statements and figured that I would just make an infinite loop that OPT_READ_TIMEOUT stops

I copied the syntax nearly verbatim from the reference manual: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/while.html

But the code below causes the error: **SQLException You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'CREATE PROCEDURE dowhile() BEGIN DECLARE v1 INT DEFAULT 5; WHILE v1 > 0 DO SET v' at line 1 (MySQL error code: 1064, SQLState: 42000)**

```
try
{
    sql::Statement* stmt = con->createStatement();
    sql::ResultSet* res = stmt->executeQuery(
        "USE orderdata; "
        "CREATE PROCEDURE dowhile() "
        "BEGIN "
            "DECLARE v1 INT DEFAULT 5; "
            "WHILE v1 > 0 DO "
                "SET v1 = v1 - 1; "
            "END WHILE; "
        "END;"
    );

    delete res;
    delete stmt;

} catch (sql::SQLException &e) {
    std::cout   << "SQLException " << e.what()
                << " (MySQL error code: " << e.getErrorCode()
                << ", SQLState: " << e.getSQLState() << ")\n";

    // Code to deal with timeout
}
```

If I don't have the statement `USE orderdata;` then I get **SQLException No database selected (MySQL error code: 1046, SQLState: 3D000)**

The above is not an infinite loop, I have just been trying to get a while loop working. Ideally it would loop forever and not require any mention of specific databases, tables, etc.

If it is important, I am using MySQL version 5.6.22 for Linux

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't have any previous experience with MySQL functions or procedures, but I managed to create something that will always cause OPT_READ_TIMEOUT to be triggered. Figured I would post it because it works but if someone else can improve it I'll accept that anser

It would be nice if a database / table didn't have to be used

```
try
{
    sql::Statement* stmt = con->createStatement();

    // Must use some database to avoid an error
    stmt->execute("USE orderdata");

    stmt->execute("DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS forever");
    stmt->execute(
        "CREATE FUNCTION forever() "
            "RETURNS INT READS SQL DATA "
        "BEGIN "
            "WHILE 1 END WHILE; "
            "RETURN 1; "
        "END;"
    );

    sql::ResultSet* res = stmt->executeQuery(
        "SELECT 1 FROM transaction WHERE forever()"
    );

    delete res;
    delete stmt;

} catch (sql::SQLException &e) {
    // Code for dealing with timeout (error 2013) in here
}
```

**Edit**: The above appears to be unreliable when having the while loop do nothing, replace `BEGIN ... END` with this:

```
"BEGIN "
    "DECLARE foo INT DEFAULT 0; "
    "WHILE 1 DO "
        "SET foo = foo + 1; "
    "END WHILE; "
    "RETURN 1; "
"END;"
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is you are trying to execute multiple queries in a single statement, namely `USE` and `CREATE PROCEDURE`. Try to use them in separate subsequent queries.
Alternatively, you can "qualify" the names by prepending the database name to the object name, like `orderdata.dowhile`.

Comment: If I first do `USE ...` and then `CREATE PROCEDURE dowhile() BEGIN ...` then I get **SQLException PROCEDURE dowhile already exists (MySQL error code: 1304, SQLState: 42000)**. If I remove `CREATE PROCEDURE dowhile()` then I get **SQLException You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'DECLARE v1 INT DEFAULT 5; WHILE v1 > 0 DO SET v1 = v1 - 1; END WHILE; END' at line 1 (MySQL error code: 1064, SQLState: 42000)**

Comment: I made something that works (and made an answer below), thank you for your answer, had no idea why I was getting that error